# In JSS Integrated Mode, how can I log errors / console output from Node to a custom logger instead of the Sitecore log?

Tags: jss

By default, the JSS Node.js rendering engine captures console output / errors emitted by the Node instance(s) rendering your JSS app and logs the output / errors to the default Sitecore log.

I would like to replace the built-in JSS/Sitecore logger with a custom logger, how can I go about doing so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To implement a custom logger, you'll need to implement a type that extends the `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.ILogger` interface from the `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices` assembly.

(For reference, use your favorite disassembler to inspect the default JSS/Sitecore implementation that logs Node.js output to Sitecore logs in the `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.Logger` class in the `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node` assembly.)

You'll then need to register your `ILogger` implementation with the Sitecore DI container with something like this (where `MyCustomLogger` is your custom implementation of `ILogger`:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Sitecore.DependencyInjection;
using Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class RegisterDependenciesPatch : IServicesConfigurator
    {
        public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            var toRemove = serviceCollection.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(ILogger));
            serviceCollection.Remove(toRemove);
            serviceCollection.AddTransiet<ILogger, MyCustomLogger>();
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, you'll need to patch the `App_Config/Sitecore/JavaScriptServices/Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.config` file to add your dependency registration code *after* the default JSS Node services dependency registrations. Example:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <configurator
      type="MyNamespace.RegisterDependenciesPatch, MyLibrary"
      patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.RegisterDependencies, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node']"
    />
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```